# Numpy : convert 2D array to 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, dimension

I have a **2 dimensional array** : `A = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])` and would like to convert it to a **3 dimensional array** : `B = numpy.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]])`

Is there a simple way to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add a new axis at the start with [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) -

```
import numpy as np

B = A[np.newaxis,:,:]
```

We could skip listing the trailing axes -

```
B = A[np.newaxis]
```

Also, bring in the alias `None` to replace `np.newaxis` for a more compact solution -

```
B = A[None]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to create a new NumPy array by using the constructor so that it takes in a list.  This list contains a single element which is the array `A` and it will allow you to create same array with the singleton dimension being the first one.  The result would be the 3D array you desire:

```
B = numpy.array([A])
```

## Example Output

```
In [13]: import numpy as np

In [14]: A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

In [15]: B = np.array([A])

In [16]: B
Out[16]:
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]]])
```